# how can i use redux flutter thunk action in a future builder

Tags: flutter, redux-thunk, flutter-futurebuilder

```
FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
    future: store.dispatch(fetchHomeAction()), // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
      List<Widget> children;
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        children = <Widget>[
          const Icon(
            Icons.check_circle_outline,
            color: Colors.green,
            size: 60,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
            child: Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}'),
          ),
        ];
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        children = <Widget>[
          const Icon(
            Icons.error_outline,
            color: Colors.red,
            size: 60,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
            child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
          ),
        ];
      } else {
        children = const <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            width: 60,
            height: 60,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
            child: Text('Awaiting result...'),
          ),
        ];
      }
      return Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: children,
        ),
      );
    },
  )
```

Here I have this code which is a future builder and the future is going to fetch the data, i have a repository and a thunk action when i am putting repository function it works. but in terms of thunk action it keeps loading loading. is there any way to solve this issue. TIA.

```
class HomeViewRepository {
  Future<HomeResponse> fetchHome() async {
    // print(id);

    var baseUrl = "${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/member/view-contact-store";
    var accessToken = prefs.getString("_accessToken");

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl), headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer $accessToken"
    });

    var responseBody = homeResponseFromJson(response.body);

    return responseBody;
  }
}
```

Thunk action::

```
ThunkAction<AppState> fetchHomeAction() {
  return (Store<AppState> store) async {
    print('thunk action post contact view');

    try {
      dynamic data = await HomeViewRepository().fetchHome();

      if (data.result == true) {
        store.dispatch(HomeResponse(
          result: data.result,
          data: data.data,
        ));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  };
}
```

so here is the thunk action that i want to call from futurebuilder.
but it doesn't work. it's runs again and again.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include the relevant code as a properly formatted and readable code snippet. Images of code are less accessible, can be more difficult to read, and are not copy/pasteable. See [mcve].

Comment: i have edited it. can you please review it